# Positioning of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web app I have a line which looks like this:

```
small textbox         large textbox        select list
```

I have a method which is boolean. If it returns false, I need to make the upper line look like this:

```
small textbox        select list
large textbox
```

Basically, I need to add a second line with the large textbox.

How to do this?

Here is some code:

```
<div>
<input style="width:25px; top:0px; left:0px; margin:0px; background:white;" type="text" />
<input style="width:100%; top:0px; left:150px; margin:0px; background:white; float:left;" />
<select style="width:60px;">
    <option value="0">a</option>
    <option value="1">b</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: If we could look at some code, that would help.

Comment: @SethenMaleno I added some code.

Comment: @Scree what does your javascript look like?  Also, from the layout, I am assuming you need the small and large text box more or less stacked on top of each other?

Comment: @SethenMaleno What javascript? Right now I don't use JS to position the elements. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @Scree You tagged this under Javascript and said in your OP that you had a boolean that returns true or false..  Did I miss something here or are you looking for someone to write the Javascript for you?

Comment: @SethenMaleno I'm asking how to make the second textbox to appear below the other two. Do I do it with appending a <br/> tag (which I think doesn't work)?

Comment: Right, so you're looking for javascript to rearrange the DOM elements based on a true or false, yes?  If you're not, I don't why you wouldn't just put the first two inputs in a wrapper div.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Yes. I already have the part which tells me if it's true or false, so how to position them?

Comment: @Scree this is what I was asking.  I wanted to see what you had so far  with Javascript.

Comment: @SethenMaleno I tried adding a <br/> tag but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, if you're looking to wrap elements in different wrappers depending on true or false, it probably boils down to an `if` statement and using jQuery's various `wrap` methods.  That's where I would start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J6kNu/)

Hope this helps. Just replace the if conditions. This is not update with the new code you posted.